# ember data serializer data mapping

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember & ember-data to try and consume a json feed from the server. Here is my code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

DS.RESTAdapter.configure(
    "plurals", {
        category: 'categories'
    }
);

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        url: 'app'
    })
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('categories');
});

App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Category.find();
    }
});

var attr = DS.attr;

App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string')
});
```

Now this works fine with a testing server.
Using the following JSON

```
{
    "categories":[
        {
            "name":"Beef",
            "id":1
        },
        {
            "name":"Pork",
            "id":2
        }
    ]
}
```

However in production the server provide the following json:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "message":"Request successful",
    "total":2,
    "data":[
        {
            "name":"Beef",
            "id":1
        },
        {
            "name":"Pork",
            "id":2
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to use the serializer to consume the live json. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I've since tried to write the serializer but it doesn't appear to be working...

see below

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        url: 'app',
        serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
            extract: function(loader, json, type, record) {
                var root = 'data';
                this.sideload(loader, type, json, root);
                this.extractMeta(loader, type, json);
                if (json[root]) {
                    if (record) { loader.updateId(record, json[root]); }
                    this.extractRecordRepresentation(loader, type, json[root]);
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Which now produces this error `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key data but you have no mapping for it`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options

- make your server compatible, and let it returns the json as ember data expects it,
- write your own adapter/serializer to support this format.

UPDATE: write your own serializer
UPDATE 2: get rid of unused functions

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L196

You can inherit from the `DS.RESTSerializer` and change `extract` with this code

```
  extract: function(loader, json, type, record) {
    var root = 'data';

    if (json[root]) {
      if (record) { loader.updateId(record, json[root]); }
      this.extractRecordRepresentation(loader, type, json[root]);
    }
  }
```

This assumes that the content of request will always be under the `data` key of your json.

Comment: For some reason the extract override doesn't seem to trigger :(

Comment: Do you inherit from `DS.RESTSerializer` and set the new serializer on the adapter?

Comment: Hi there, I've edited the question with the new serializer code, it just doesn't appear to work as expected.

Comment: The problem is that the serializer doesn't know what is the type of data that is received. I need to think a litte bit more.

Comment: As the serializer can't deduce the type from the json, the adapter will need to capture this information while making the xhr request.

Comment: I have removed 2 lines from the `extract` method. This removes support for sideloading, but your backend can't produce it anyway.