# Ember.js changing RESTAdapter JSON serialization

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that I'm querying from an API:

```
App.Deal = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  value_in_cents: DS.attr('number'),
  closed_time: DS.attr('date'),
  user: DS.attr('object'),
  company: DS.attr('object')
});
```

The API returns something like:

```
{ 
  pagination: { page: 1, total: 10 },
  entries: [ deal1, deal2, deal3, deal4 ]
}
```

I've updated my Adapter to be the following:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  url: 'http://api.pipelinedeals.com/api/v3',
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractMany: function(loader, json, type, records) {
      var root = this.rootForType(type);
      var roots = this.pluralize(root);

      formattedJson = {};
      formattedJson[roots] = json.entries;
      delete formattedJson.pagination;
      this._super(loader, formattedJson, type, records);
    }
  })
});
```

`newJson` has the format I want, but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You tried to use a attribute type (object) that has not been registered ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js:52
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure that `var roots = this.pluralize(root); // deals` returns really "deals" as a String?

Comment: You don't want to use the `DS.RESTAdapter` with the `DS.JSONSerializer`. It won't work (or you will have unexpected behaviors at some point).

Comment: See this other SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037175/ember-data-serializer-data-mapping/16042261#16042261 to customize your serializer.

Comment: Yup roots works as expected. Makes sense, i'll use DS.JSONSerializer instead. By overriding the `extract` method, i now get the following error: Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key pagination but you have no mapping for it ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js:52
Ember.assert ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js:52
DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.sideload ember-data.js:6602
DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.extractMany ember-data.js:6546
superWrapper ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js:947

Comment: Also, this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037175/ember-data-serializer-data-mapping/16042261#16042261) overrides the `extract` method, while `extractMany` comes before it, so i get an error b/c of the failure in `this.sideload`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what build of ember data are you using? there have been many new fixes recently

Answer (score 0):

You want to inherit from `DS.RESTSerializer` and override `extractMany` to have something like this:

```
extractMany: function(loader, json, type, records) {
    var root = 'entries';

    if (json[root]) {
      var objects = json[root], references = [];
      if (records) { records = records.toArray(); }

      for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (records) { loader.updateId(records[i], objects[i]); }
        var reference = this.extractRecordRepresentation(loader, type, objects[i]);
        references.push(reference);
      }

      loader.populateArray(references);
    }
  },
```

As your server doesn't set the type as a root, you won't be able to use sideloading anyway.

Comment: `loader.populateArray(references)` is the line that throws "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You tried to use a attribute type (object) that has not been registered ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js:52" I've gotten that in a few variations. What does that even mean?