# changing the root of the EmberJS RESTSerializer

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, instagram

The data I'm consuming looks a lot like Instagram's [User Model Response](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users).  Rather than the properties sitting on the root level, they are in a "data" object, one level in.  And further complicating things, there are deeply embedded objects.

**EDIT**

I'm editing the data to better represent the actual model I'm working with.

```
{
    {
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "..."
        "next_max_id": "..."
    },
    "data": {
        "name": "I'm Making Coffee",
        "film_id": "...",
        "duration": 55,
        "picture": "https://directr.blob.core.windows.net/prints/nb8yr_print_H360.jpg",
        "print": {
            "print_id": "...",
            "url": "...",
            "formats": [
                "mp4",
                "ogg",
                "jpg"
            ],
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540
                },
                {
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 360
                },
                {
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                }
            ]
        },
        "comments": {
            "count": 0,
            "data": []
        },
        "hearts": {
            "count": 2,
            "data": [
                {
                    "user_id": "55555",
                    "alias": "jonah"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "66666",
                    "alias": "eli"
                }
            ]
        },
        "directrs": {
            "count": 1,
            "data": [
                {
                    "user_id": "55555",
                    "name": "jonah",
                    "picture": "/api/picture.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

The this film model is pretty deeply embedded.  The root of the data is one level deep under data.

The pagination would be useful to pass on to a different control, and the http status response I don't need, or want to model, at all.  It looks as though I'd also need to separate "comments," "hearts," and certainly "print" into their own models and create relationships to bind them.

I've tried looking through the source, and I cannot figure out where in the flow I need to be hooking in to cut this JSON into the format I need... whether I can just point to the correct "root" of the object in an Ember way, or if I can just hack up the JSON before it's processed.

Ember's mission to abtract all this away is a wonderful goal.  I wish I could just grok the source... :)  Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about related objects ? Do they exist in that api or is what you have the most complex example with pagination (nothing nested under data itself)

Comment: You can customize your adapter to support that payload. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037175/ember-data-serializer-data-mapping/16042261#16042261

Comment: @ToranBillups - I didn't want to overwhelm with the complexity of our actual JSON model, but now realize it's far less helpful if I simplify it so much.  Sorry and thanks :)

Comment: @Cyril - great. looking into that.  so, to model all the embedded objects correctly (see edited JSON above), can I simply modify the JSON object within the overwritten extract function?  (The JSON api can't change right now)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of webapi_adapter.js and webapi_serializer.js file from https://github.com/xqiu/MVCSPAWithEmberjs/tree/master/MvcSPAWithEmberjs/Scripts/app , I created them for the ember.js SPA template for Visual Studio 2012 update 2 MVC4 SPA template.

I have to change the root node and do other compromises to get the WebAPI returned JSON compatible with ember-data.